# Why can I not print the entire message in this file using C?

Tags: c

```
char message[500];
printf("\nEnter your message (Not more than 500 words)\n->");
scanf("%s", message);

FILE *ptr;
ptr = fopen("file.txt", "w");

fprintf(ptr, message);
fclose(ptr);
```

Here I created an array called message and after receiving the input from the user, I printed the stored string into the file named 'file.txt' but it turns out that only first word of the message array is printing in the file.
For example: If I typed 'Hello there, I am learning C' inside the message array and print it to the file, then only 'hello' is being printed on the file.
Please explain elaborately.

Comment: `scanf` stops at the first whitespace. Just put a `printf("message = %s\n", message);` right after the scanf and you'll see. Use `fgets` instead of `scanf`.

Comment: If message contains % then your code will fail because there is no format.

Comment: In your question, your prompt the user to enter "not more than 500 words". However, your program is only able to store up to 500 **characters**, not **words**. If you don't count the terminating null character, it is actually 499 characters.

Answer (score 4):

*never* use `%s` in scanf without a maximum field width, or you may very likely overflow your buffer.  Using `%s` is no better than `gets`.

The issue you are having is simply that `%s` reads up until the first whitespace.  If you want to consume all input, you probably should use `fread` instead of `scanf`.  That is:

```
char message[500];
printf("\nEnter your message (Not more than 500 characters)\n->");
size_t s = fread(message, 1, sizeof message - 1, stdin);
message[s] = '\0';
```

If you want to read only one line of text, you could use `fgets`.  If you want to use scanf to read only one line, you could do: `scanf("%499[^\n]", message);` (Note that this is significantly different than `%499s` in that it will not discard leading whitespace, and stops only at the first line break rather than the first whitespace character.)  If you want to use `scanf` to read the entire input stream, you could try something like `scanf("%499[^\1]", message);` which would probably be adequate for textual input.

Whatever input method you use, make sure you check the return value.  If `scanf` fails to assign an input item (eg, because the input does not match the format string), then reading that item may invoke undefined behavior.  If `fread` returns 0, or (in this case) 499, you will want to add logic to decide what to do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Because it seems the OP is trying to consume all of the input rather than just one line.